# platform.ready() method is not firing in Android device using ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, file-transfer, platform

**I am Developing an Ionic Application that Upload, downloads, and delete attachments**
Here I use the File Plugin inside the platform. ready() and build APK. when I run the APK on an android device the code inside the Platform.ready is not getting fired what is the problem???

```
 import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
 import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
 constructor(private cFile: File,private platform: Platform){}
 DownloadAttachment()
 {
  var buffer = pFilebytearray.replace(/\"/g, "");
var byteCharacters = atob(buffer);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
this.cFile.dataDirectory
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
let aType: any = "";
let aMimeTypeJson = {} as any;
aMimeTypeJson = this.GetMimeType(pAttachmentType.toLowerCase())
aType = aMimeTypeJson.MimeType;
var blob1 = new Blob([byteArray], { type: aType });
alert("completed the Name Seperation and Blob Creation")
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  alert("Download Starts...");
  let result = this.cFile.createDir(this.cFile.externalDataDirectory, "Documents", true).then(data => {
    let dirpath = data.toURL();
    alert("Dir created at" + dirpath);
    this.cFile.writeFile(dirpath, pAttachmentName, blob1, { replace: true })
      .then((Result) => {
        this.MessageDialog("Message", "Attachment downloaded " + dirpath, false, true);
      }, (error) => {
        this.MessageDialog("Message", "Attachment not downloaded", false, true);
      });

  }).catch(error => {
    alert("error" + error);

  });


})

 }
```

Comment: what is the need of `platform.ready()`? try downloading your file with `platform.ready()`. or wrap your complete function inside `platform.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

The Error Solved for me after using Async, await. This makes the code wait till the platform gets ready

```
async AttachmentDownload(pFilebytearray, pAttachmentType, pAttachmentName): Promise<void> {
    alert("entering AttachmentDownload")
    var buffer = pFilebytearray.replace(/\"/g, "");
    var byteCharacters = atob(buffer);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    this.cFile.dataDirectory
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    let aType: any = "";
    let aMimeTypeJson = {} as any;
    aMimeTypeJson = this.GetMimeType(pAttachmentType.toLowerCase())
    aType = aMimeTypeJson.MimeType;
    var blob1 = new Blob([byteArray], { type: aType });
    alert("completed the Name Seperation and Blob Creation")
    await this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      alert("Download Starts...");
      let result = this.cFile.createDir(this.cFile.externalDataDirectory, "Documents", true).then(data => {
        let dirpath = data.toURL();
        alert("Dir created at" + dirpath);
        this.cFile.writeFile(dirpath, pAttachmentName, blob1, { replace: true })
          .then((Result) => {
            this.MessageDialog("Message", "Attachment downloaded " + dirpath, false, true);
          }, (error) => {
            this.MessageDialog("Message", "Attachment not downloaded", false, true);
          });

      }).catch(error => {
        alert("error" + error);

      });
    })
}
```